# LinkButton OnClick() doesnt hit the srcipt function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my aspx page, I has a Linkbutton `linkbtTitle` inside a Repeater Control:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
  <script runat="server">  
    protected void Buttonlink_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton linkbtTitle = (LinkButton)sender;
        linkbtTitle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.HotPink;//change color when selected
        linkbtTitle.Font.Underline = true;
        linkbtTitle.Font.Italic = true;
     }  
  </script> 
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" /> 
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TITLE")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' OnCommand="linkbtTitle_Click" OnClick="Buttonlink_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>                               

    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 

    </asp:Content>
```

I use method `OnCommand="linkbtTitle_Click"` to auto download attachment when client click on  `Linkbutton` and `OnClick="Buttonlink_Click"` to change color of selected Linkbutton.

When I built this page, the attachment is downloaded automatically but the Selected LinkButton doesnt change its color.

Try to debug, function Buttonlink_Click() is not called, it has an message: `Expression Statement is not assignment or call` when hovering mouse on statement: `... OnClick="Buttonlink_Click" ...`

I wonder if there is some problem in `linkbtTitle_Click` Please take a look at my code behind:

```
public void linkbtTitle_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       //auto download the attachment when selected
        int mamd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        string sql = "select * from MAU_DON where MA_MAU_DON="+mamd;
        DataTable maudon = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);

        string attachment = dirPath["MAU_DON"].DIRECTORY + @"/" + maudon.Rows[0]["PATH"].ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
          "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(attachment));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: U haven't use javascript then also u have INSERTED tag... why so???

Comment: And one more thing my friend in repeater u can not call Click event.... for that u need to use itemdatabound event...

Comment: @Rony I have used Click Event for many time before, I can do it by casting it: LinkButton linkbtTitle =  (LinkButton ) sender;

Comment: @Rony as you recommended, I've just inserted tag: type="text/javascript" but nothing happen

Comment: But my friend u r using it in repeater.... so click event IN REPEATER is only possible in Itemdatabound... and where is your javascript????

Answer (score 0):

It will not hit the server side function. The eventing mechanism is slightly altered when a control like linkbutton or even a normal button itself is used in the item template. Instead of the onclick event firing, an event on the repeater will fire...its called ItemCommand. This happens via a mechanism called event bubbling.

To know which button caused it, you need to use the CommandName and CommandArgument.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" CommandName="foo" CommandArgument="<%# Eval ("Id") %>" Text="FooBtn" />
```

In the code behind, the repeater's item command event, we write something like

```
if (e.CommandName == "foo") 
{
    // so we know what button triggered this
    // access the value of e.CommandArgument to get associated row data.
}
```